# Use result of Get-WMIObject to do nslookup

Tags: powershell

The purpose of my script is:

- Ask the user for input (in this case a username)
- Run `Get-WMIObject Win32_Serverconnection` and filter on username

So far so good, I get the result I'm looking for. BUT sometimes `computername` contains an IPv4 address, sometimes a hostname and sometimes an IPv6 address.

If it shows up as an IPv6 address, it's useless for the purpose of the script so I thought I would use `nslookup` in the end to get the proper information.

But when I assign the result of `Get-WMIOBject` to a variable I cant seem to use the variable with `nslookup`.

The results usually includes several computernames (hostnames) and when `nslookup` runs it includes the string `computername=`. So it can't resolve.

Example:

```
cant resolve {@computername=[85.23.444.200]}
```

Sorry that I can't provide you with my code so far but I have it at work and I'm at home right now.

Comment: Use `$variable.computername`. `computername` is a property of the object stored in `$variable`. `nslookup $variable.computername` should work.

Comment: _Sorry that I can't provide you with my code so far but I have it at work and I'm at home right now._ There is a problem with your code. Kind of hard to fix unless you show us normally. That being said your issue is that you are not expanding your variable like sodawillow points out.

Comment: Thanks alot, I will try that tomorrow when I'm at work and get back here with the results.

Answer (score 2):

nslookup is a CMD application and while you can create variables from PowerShell objects and pass them as strings to CMD apps doing anything after that is difficult because the output is text not object based. You're much better off using the PowerShell `Resolve-DNSName`.

You have two options. You can do it as a script:

```
$What = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_ServerConnection

$What | % {
    $ComputerName = (Resolve-DNSName $_.ComputerName).NameHost
    $ComputerName
}
```

Or as a one liner:

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_ServerConnection | Select *,@{n='Hostname';e={(Resolve-DnsName $_.ComputerName).NameHost}}
```

Which will add an additional property called 'Hostname' with the resolved DNS name.

Disclaimer: Resolve-DNSName is only available on Windows Server 2012 R2 / Windows 8.1 and newer. On older machines you would need to use something like `[Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry("IP")`. In any case nslookup should be avoided if you want to do anything useful with the information without doing a bunch of conversion.

To demonstrate the difference:

```
[nick@nick-lt scripts]# $resolve = Resolve-DnsName 8.8.8.8
[nick@nick-lt scripts]# $resolve

Name                           Type   TTL   Section    NameHost
----                           ----   ---   -------    --------
8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa           PTR    1772  Answer     google-public-dns-a.google.com


[nick@nick-lt scripts]# Test-NetConnection $resolve.NameHost


ComputerName           : google-public-dns-a.google.com
RemoteAddress          : 8.8.8.8
InterfaceAlias         : Ethernet
SourceAddress          : 10.87.102.133
PingSucceeded          : True
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 60 ms



[nick@nick-lt scripts]# $nslookup = nslookup 8.8.8.8
[nick@nick-lt scripts]# $nslookup
Server:  redacted
Address:  10.87.1.11

Name:    google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

[nick@nick-lt scripts]# Test-NetConnection $nslookup.name
Resolve-DnsName : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\NetTCPIP\Test-NetConnection.psm1:315 char:74
+ ... ctionResult.DNSOnlyRecords = @( Resolve-DnsName $ComputerName -DnsOnl ...
+                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Resolve-DnsName], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.DnsClient.Commands.ResolveDnsName
```

Once you start using CMD applications you're ability to use the results between steps in your script becomes far more complicated.

Comment: Thanks alot for taking time to describe those kind of things. Very useful information for a beginner like myself. I'll get back to this thread tomorrow when I'm at work.